# Prove that convolution with a separable filter is equivalent to convolution on each 1D filter

Tags: filters, convolution, proof

I would like to prove that convolution of an image $I \in \mathcal{M}_{m_1 \times n_1}$ with respect to a separable 2D filter $F$, (i.e., $F = F_1 F_2$, where $F \in \mathcal{M}_{m_2\times n_2}(\mathbb{R})$, $F_1 \in \mathcal{M}_{m_2\times1}$, and $F_2 \in \mathcal{M}_{1\times n_2}$) is equivalent to convolution with respect to $F_1$ and then $F_2$. If $A*B$ represents convolution of an image matrix $A$ under a filter matrix $B$, then we need to show that $I*F=(I*F_1)*F_2$.

We define convolution as such: $(I*F)_{(m,n)} = \sum_{i=-m_2/2}^{m_2/2}\sum_{j=-n_2/2}^{n_2/2}F[i,j]\cdot I[m-i,n-j]$, or $\sum_{i=-m_2/2}^{m_2/2}\sum_{j=-n_2/2}^{n_2/2} I[i,j]\cdot F[m-i,n-j]$.

Here's what I've tried starting with the left side (using the matrix indexing notation [m,n]):

$((I*F_1)*{F_2}){[m,n]} = \sum_{j=-n_2/2}^{n_2/2}(\sum_{i=-m_2/2}^{m_2/2}{I{[m-i,n-1]}} \cdot {{F_1}{[i,1]}}){[m-1,n-j]}{F_2}{[1,j]}$

Now, I notice that the terms ${F_1}{[i,1]}$ and $F_2[1,j]$ as placed in the summations can be combined to yield $F[i,j]$, however, we are indexing this entire term, so I don't believe we can combine these two terms as such. Additionally, the I don't see how to get terms involving $I$ to become $I[m-i,n-j]$.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let the 2D sequence $x[n,m]$ represent the original image, using the following convention: $n$ is horizontal-right, $m$ is vertical-up, and the origin is at the bottom left.

Consider a separable 2D sequence $h[n,m] = f[n]g[m]$ where $f[n]$ and $g[m]$ are the corresponding 1D horizontal and vertical sequences respectively.

The output 2D sequence of the convolution is $$y[n,m] = x[n,m]\star h[n,m].$$

Write the convolutiom sum:

$$ \begin{align}
y[n,m] &= \sum_k \sum_r h[n-k,m-r] x[k,r] \\
&= \sum_k  \sum_r f[n-k] g[m-r] x[k,r] \\
&= \sum_k  f[n-k] \left( \sum_r g[m-r] x[k,r] \right) \\
\end{align}
$$

recognize the following: The summation inside the brackets indicate a 1D convolution between the sequence $g[m]$ and the $k-th$ column of the original image: $x[k,m]$. Remember that during the summation, the dummy index $k$ is fixed, whereas the other dummy index $r$ is ranging through the vertical samples of $x[k,r]$. Denote this **intermediate** sum as a new 2D sequence $w[k,m]$, parametrized according to $k$ and $m$. This's the intermediate image defined for each $k$ & $m$, and formed by convolving each column-$k$ of $x[n,m]$ by the sequence $g[m]$.

Then the equation follows as:
$$ \begin{align}
y[n,m]  &= \sum_k  f[n-k] \left( \sum_r g[m-r] x[k,r] \right) \\
&= \sum_k  f[n-k] w[k,m] \\
y[n,m] &= f[n] \star w[n,m] \\
\end{align}
$$

Where, the last line represents a 1D convolution between the **rows** of the intermediate image (for each fixed $m$) and the 1D sequence $f[n]$ along horizontal direction, finishing the proof.